# Why does C++ not have a const constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

(*Edit: Heavy change because previous example was flawed, which may make some answers/comments seem odd)*

This might be an overly contrived, but the following is legal because of lack of const constructor:

```
class Cheater
{
public:
    Cheater(int avalue) 
       : cheaterPtr(this) //conceptually odd legality in const Cheater ctor
       , value(avalue) 
    {}

    Cheater& getCheaterPtr() const {return *cheaterPtr;}
    int value;

private:
    Cheater * cheaterPtr;
};

int main()
{
    const Cheater cheater(7); //Initialize the value to 7

    cheater.value                 = 4;    //good, illegal
    cheater.getCheaterPtr().value = 4;    //oops, legal

    return 0;
}
```

It seems like providing a const constructor a thing would be as easy technically as const methods, and be analogous to a const overload.

*Note: I'm not looking for '`Image( const Data & data ) const`' but rather '`const Image( const Data & data) const`'*

So:

- Why is the const constructor absent in C++?

Here's some related material for context:

- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0798.htm
- [How to deal with initialization of non-const reference member in const object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699307/how-to-deal-with-initialization-of-non-const-member-in-const-object/6936079#6936079)
- [C++, Classes, Const, and strange syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656664/c-classes-const-and-strange-syntax)

Comment: "The const constructor" isn't _absent_ in C++, it's something you made up just now.

Comment: Also, what would be the advantages of this?

Comment: Seth: This must make sense in some mindset where copy constructors take pointers instead of references. Not sure where.

Comment: @honk These are not copy constructors.

Comment: This seems like a contradiction: a member function that is const promises not to modify member variables, so a const constructor would also have to abide by that. However a constructor's purpose is to modify it's member variables, hence the contradiction.

Comment: @sashang agreed. It would not be a const method itself, but return a const pointer to a new object but only be allowed in the case of `new const` in sort of the same way that non-const methods are *not* allowed to be used on with const objects.

Comment: Doesn't this accomplish the same thing? ``const Image img(data);``

Comment: @unluddite, it doesn't because I would need to have a constructor which takes a const pointer for it to work which would not compile.

Comment: Really? http://ideone.com/nQbD8 (unless I'm totally missing the argument here, which is a great possibility).

Comment: @unluddite the important part is that your internal data is const. http://ideone.com/ngu5T would be an example of what doesn't work.

Comment: @Catskul: So, what you're asking for is the ability to create an object that can _never_ be accessed in a non-const way. And therefore, you could (theoretically) initialize non-const members with const values because those non-const members would syntactically become const, by virtue of using the const-only constructor.

Comment: @Nicol, Yes, I think that's a concise way of putting it.

Comment: I realized some time ago that methods such as your `getCheaterPtr()` shouldn't be const! Because it allows the caller to modify internal state of your object. But const constructors would be useful in other applications.

Comment: @sashang et al "However a constructor's purpose is to modify it's member variables" - no, constructor purpose is to INITIALIZE its member variables. This is a huge difference. Note that when you create plain const bultin you also have to initialize it, otherwise it's useless. So it should be clear that when you do something like: `const int x = 6`, you *initialize* `x` - not *modify* it. Above is bad example, but const constructors should exist and they would be useful in other applications.

Comment: A related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773397/if-class-a-modifies-its-construction-parameters-can-i-initialize-const-as-with) of mine may be relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It would not be a const method itself

If this constructor were not a `const` method itself, then the internal pointers and such would also not be `const`. Therefore, it could not set `const` values into those non-`const` members.

The only way to make it work syntactically is for this constructor to require member initialization for all non-`mutable` members. Essentially, any member not declared `mutable` would be implicitly declared `const` when using this constructor. Which is equivalent to making the constructor a `const` method; only initializers could initialize members. The constructor's body could do nothing with non-mutable members, because those members would be `const` at that point.

What you are asking for is syntactically dubious. You're essentially trying to hoodwink the API, storing constant data in an object that is designed for mutable data (which is why you didn't declare the member pointer to be `const`). If you want different behavior for an object, you need to declare the object to have that specific behavior.

Comment: It's a good point that everything would have to be initialized via initializers. Though, I don't know that I agree that it would be syntactically dubious since const is regularly used otherwise as a contract, and I think would be used in that sense here.

Comment: This answer also has confused the difference between `const T*` and `T * const`.

Comment: @Ben: Actually, I think he got it correctly. My example was flawed, but the technical issue seems to be that a const constructor would have to treat this as a pointer-to-const and that would be awkward. I think this might be the closest thing to a satisfying answer.

Comment: That ... does not follow. A const constructor would be just like a non-const constructor, with the only difference that the so-constructed object would be const-qualified at the end of construction.

Comment: Copy assignment to const qualified object (const T t = object) is valid via a const qualified member method, so why would the same behavior in a constructor be syntactically dubious?

Answer (score 11):

Just because `Image` is `const` in your imaginary constructor doesn't mean that what `m_data` points to is. You'd end up being able to assign a "pointer to const" to a "const pointer to non-const" inside your class, which would remove constness without a cast. This would obviously allow you to violate invariants and couldn't be allowed.

As far as I know, any specific sets of const-ness that are needed can be accurately and completely specified within the current standard.

Another way to look at it is that `const` means the method doesn't mutate your object's state. A constructor's sole purpose is to initialize an object's state to be valid (well hopefully anyway - any constructors with side effects should be ...carefully evaluated).

EDIT: In C++ constness applies to both members, and for pointers and references, to the accessible constness of the referred object. C++ consciously made the decision to split out these two different const-nesses. Firstly, do we agree that this code demonstrating the difference should compile and print out "non-const"?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Data
{
    void non_const() { std::cout << "non-const" << std::endl; }
};

struct Image
{
     Image(             Data & data ) : m_data( data ) {}

     void check() const { m_data.non_const(); }
     Data & m_data;
};

int main()
{
    Data data;
    const Image img(data);
    img.check();

    return 0;
}
```

So then in order to obtain the behavior where it could accept a const-ref and store it as const-ref, the effective declaration of the reference would have to change to be const. This would then mean that it would be a completely distinct type, NOT a `const` version of the original type (since two types with members differing in const-qualification are treated as two separate types in C++). Thus, either the compiler has to be able to do excessive behind-the-scenes magic to convert these things back and forth, remembering the const-ness of the members, or it has to treat it as a separate type which then couldn't be used in place of the normal type.

I think what you're trying to achieve is a referencee_const object, a concept that only exists in C++ as a separate class (which I suspect could be implemented with judicious use of templates although I didn't make an attempt).

Is this strictly a theoretical question (answer: C++ decided to split object and referencee constness) or is there an actual practical uncontrived problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I mean to imply by my example that the const constructor overload would only be invoked with `new const Image` in which case implicit const should provide the necessary constness. I'm not looking for Image( const Data * data ) const, but rather const Image( const Data * data)

Comment: In C++ the constness of the containing class never changes `Data* data` into `const Data* data`. The change that could possibly occur would be to `Data* const data`. The pointee is still non-const. The trick is that since pointers provide indirection there are *two* places that constness can be applied: the pointer itself, and the thing being pointed to.

Comment: Mark B: good point, but if I change the pointers to const references the technical issue still stands I think. No?

Comment: Const references behave the same way as pointers in this respect - you can have a `Data & const data`

Comment: Oof. brain not working. You're right of course.  Still while my example doesn't get at the issue perhaps, the idea as brought up in the paper still stands with the question I think.

Comment: @bdonlan: No you can't, references can never be rebound, so there's no such thing as a const reference.  You're right though that having a const object doesn't turn member references into references to const.

Comment: @Ben, oops, brainfart :) I suppose you could say that references are always const... But yes, references are unchanged under the class becoming const

Comment: @Mark: I think you are certainly correct regarding my example that I misunderstood how const was working there. I need to reread the paper I linked to, but I would imagine its examples wouldn't suffer from the same misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

Mark B goes over the fundamental considerations, but note that you can do something similar in pure C++. Consider:

```
struct Data { };

class ConstImage {
protected:
  const Data *const_data;
public:
  ConstImage (const Data *cd) : const_data(cd) { }
  int getFoo() const { return const_data->getFoo(); }
};

class Image : public ConstImage {
protected:
  Data *data() { return const_cast<Data *>(const_data); }
public:
  Image(Data *d) : const_data(d) { }
  void frob() { data()->frob(); }
};
```

Instead of using `const Image *`, use `ConstImage *`, and there you go. You could also simply define a static function pseudo-constructor:

```
const Image *Image::newConstImage(const Data *d) {
  return new Image(const_cast<Data*>(d));
}
```

This, of course, relies on the programmer to ensure that there aren't any `const` functions which might somehow mutate the pointed-to `Data`'s state.

You can also combine these techniques:

```
class Image {
protected:
  const Data *const_data;
  Data *data() { return const_cast<Data *>(const_data); }
public:
  void frob() { data()->frob(); }
  int getFoo() const { return const_data->getFoo(); }

  Image(Data *d) : const_data(d) { }

  static const Image *newConst(const Data *cd) {
    return new Image(const_cast<Data *>(cd));
  }
};
```

This gets the best of both worlds; since `data()` is a non-const member, you have static checking for mutation of the pointed-to value. You also, however, have a const constructor, and can directly cast between `Image *` and `const Image *` (ie, you can remove the constness if you know it is safe).

You can also abstract away the separation of pointers further:

```
template<typename T>
class ConstPropPointer {
private:
  T *ptr;
public:
  ConstPropPointer(T *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_) { }
  T &operator*() { return *ptr; }
  const T &operator*() const { return *ptr; }
  T *operator->() { return ptr; }
  const T *operator->() const { return ptr; }
};


class Image {
protected:
  ConstPropPointer<Data> data;
public:
  void frob() { data->frob(); }
  int getFoo() const { return data->getFoo(); }

  Image(Data *d) : data(d) { }

  static const Image *newConst(const Data *cd) {
    return new Image(const_cast<Data *>(cd));
  }
};
```

Now, if `this` is const, `data` becomes const, propagating that into `*data` as well. Good enough for you? :)

I suppose the final answer is probably this: In order for a const constructor to be useful and safe, we'd need something like the `ConstPropPointer` you see there built into the language. Const constructors would then be allowed to assign from `const T *` to `constprop T *`. This is more complex than it sounds - for example, how does this interact with template classes such as `vector`?

So, this is a somewhat complex change, but the problem doesn't seem to come up all that much. More importantly, there's a simple workaround here (the `ConstPropPointer` can be librarized, and the static pseudo-constructor is simple enough to add). So the C++ committee probably passed it over for more important things, if it was even proposed at all.

Comment: A reasonable work around, but in it's existence reinforces the question of why a const returning constructor doesn't exist.

Comment: @Catskul, added a bit of speculation :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the fact of that the ctors haven't return-type specification is what fails here. Any other imaginable syntax like for example

```
class A
{
    const A& ctor(...);
}
```

would be, imho, very valuable. For example, imagine such a situation of calling a method with prototype

```
void my_method(const my_own_string_class& z);
```

If my_own_string_class holds a ctor from char*, the compiler could choose
this ctor, but as this ctor is not allowed to return a const object, it need to allocate and copy... If const return type were allowed, one could do

```
class my_own_string_class
{
    char *_ptr;
    public:
    const my_own_string_class& ctor(char *txt)
    : _ptr(txt)
    { return *this;}
 }
```

provided that this special construct be restricted to the creation of temporal instances. (And dtor's must be mutable ;) ).

Answer (score -2):

Const objects should initialize their member variables and a const constructor wouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: I'm not looking for `Image( const Data * data ) const`, but rather `const Image( const Data * data)`