# Why is conversion from const pointer-to-const to const pointer-to-nonconst in an initializer list allowed

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, implicit-conversion

I read the question posted on
[Why does C++ not have a const constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936124/why-does-c-not-have-a-const-constructor)

I am still confused why that program can compile. And I tried to offer my opinion on the question, I don't know why it was deleted. So I have to ask the question again.

Here is the program

```
class Cheater
{
public:
    Cheater(int avalue) :
    value(avalue),
    cheaterPtr(this) //conceptually odd legality in const Cheater ctor
    {}

    Cheater& getCheaterPtr() const {return *cheaterPtr;}
    int value;
private:
    Cheater * cheaterPtr;
};
int main()
{
    const Cheater cheater(7); //Initialize the value to 7

 //   cheater.value                 = 4;    //good, illegal
    cheater.getCheaterPtr().value = 4;    //oops, legal
    return 0;
}
```

And my confusion is :

`const Cheater cheater(7)`
creates a const object cheater, in its constructor

```
  Cheater(int avalue) :
    value(avalue),
    cheaterPtr(this) //conceptually odd legality in const Cheater ctor
{}
```

'this' pointer was used to initialize `cheaterPtr`.

I think it shouldn't be right. `cheater` is a const object, whose this pointer should be something like: `const Cheater* const this;` which means the pointer it self and the object the pointer points to should both const, we can neither change the value of the pointer or modify the object the pointer points to.

but object `cheater`'s `cheaterPtr` member is something like `Cheater* const cheaterPtr`. Which means the pointer is const but the object it points to can be nonconst.

As we know, pointer-to-const to pointer-to-nonconst conversion is not allowed:

```
int i = 0;
const int* ptrToConst = &i;
int * const constPtr = ptrToConst;  //  illegal. invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'
```

How can conversion from pointer-to-const to pointer-to-nonconst be allowed in the initializer list? What really happened?

And here is a discription about "constness" in constructors I tried to offer to the original post:

"Unlike other member functions, constructors may not be declared as const. When we create a const object of a class type, the object does not assume its 'constness' until after the constructor completes the object's initialization. Thus, constructors can write to const objects during their construction."

--C++ Primer (5th Edition) P262 7.1.4 Constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are incorrect. Taking them one at a time, first code annotation.

```
class Cheater
{
public:
    Cheater(int avalue) :
        value(avalue),
        cheaterPtr(this) // NOTE: perfectly legal, as *this is non-const
                         // in the construction context.
    {}

    // NOTE: method is viable as const. it makes no modifications
    //  to any members, invokes no non-const member functions, and
    //  makes no attempt to pass *this as a non-const parameter. the
    //  code neither knows, nor cares whether `cheaterPtr`points to
    //  *this or not.
    Cheater& getCheaterPtr() const {return *cheaterPtr;}

    int value;

private:
    Cheater * cheaterPtr; // NOTE: member pointer is non-const.
};


int main()
{
    // NOTE: perfectly ok. we're creating a const Cheater object
    //  which means we cannot fire non-const members or pass it
    //  by reference or address as a non-const parameter to anything.
    const Cheater cheater(7);

    // NOTE: completely lega. Invoking a const-method on a const
    // object. That it returns a non-const reference is irrelevant
    // to the const-ness of the object and member function.    
    cheater.getCheaterPtr().value = 4;

    return 0;
}
```

You said:

> I think it shouldn't be right. cheater is a const object whose this pointer should be something like: `const Cheater* const this`

`cheater` *is* `const` *after construction*. It must be non-const *during* construction. Further, the constructor does not (and cannot) know the *caller* has indicated the object will be `const`. All it knows is its time to construct an object, so thats what it does. Furthermore, *after* construction `&cheater` is `const Cheater *`. Making the actual pointer var itself also `const` is simply non-applicable in this context.

And then...

> ...object cheater's cheaterPtr member is something like `Cheater* const cheaterPtr;`

This is actually an incredibly accurate way to describe this. Because `cheater` is `const` its members are as well, which means the `cheaterPtr` member is `const`; **not** what it points *to*. You cannot change the pointer value, but because it is not a pointer-to-const-object you can freely use that pointer to modify what it points to, which in this case happens to be `this`.

If you wanted *both* the pointer and its pointed-to-object to be const you whould have declared it as `const Cheater *cheaterPtr;` in the member list. (and doing that, btw, makes only that mutable action through the `getCheaterPointer()` invalid. It would have to return a `const Cheater*` as well, which means of course the assignment would fail.

In short, this code is entirely valid. What you're wanting to see (construction awareness of the *callers* const-ness) is not part of the language, and indeed it cannot be if you want your constructors to have the latitude to... well, *construct*.

Comment: Oh, I got it, the this pointer is not const until the construction completes. But it seem's logically wrong: you say that the object is const, you promise not to modify it, but later on you can use this trick to modify it. Is this a flaw of C++ ?

Answer (score 3):

If constructors were `const`, they couldn't construct their object - they couldn't write into its data!

The code you cite as "legal:"

```
cheater.getCheaterPtr().value = 4;    //oops, legal
```

is not actually legal. While it compiles, its behaviour is undefined, because it modifies a `const` object through a non-const lvalue. It's exactly the same as this:

```
const int value = 0;
const int * p = &value;
*const_cast<int*>(p) = 4;
```

This will also compile, but it's still illegal (has UB).

Comment: you mean there's a implicit const_cast ?

Comment: @Linlix No. In the ctor, you have a non-const pointer to the object which is called `cheater` in `main()`. You store that pointer. When the ctor exits, `cheater` become `const`. You still have a non-const pointer to it stored. If you dereference that stored pointer and use it to modify `cheater`, you're modifying a `const` object through a non-const lvalue, so you get UB.