# Make only const copies of a const object

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

I have a class which contains references, like:

```
class A {
 A(B &b) : b(b) {} // constructor
 B &b;
}
```

Sometimes b must be read-only, sometimes it is writeable. When I make a `const A a(b);` object, it's obvious that I want to protect the data inside it as `const`.
But - by accident - it's easy to make a non-const copy of the object which will make the data inside it vulnerable.

```
const A a(b); // b object protected here
A a_non_const(a);
a_non_const.b.non_const_function(...); // b not protected now
```

I think that I should somehow prevent copies of the object when it is `const` like this:

```
const A a(b);
const A a2(a); // OK!
A a_non_const(a); // Compiler error
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Enter encapsulation.

Comment: _"Sometimes b must be read-only, sometimes it is writeable."_ All your problems stem from this weird duality. I suggest picking one set of semantics for your class, not two.

Comment: That's why you have keywords like *private* or *public*. Then you can just write accessers/modifiers that do whatever you want.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's not uncommon. I have a class `C` that does non-const operations on `b`, and other reader classes. C gets `a` as non-const, the others as const. I am looking for a way to protect `b` in other classes.

Comment: @BillKotsias: I agree that bad/problematic designs are not uncommon. Whether you improve it is of course your call

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for your kind words and helpful comment

Comment: No problem- good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### flaw in your code: your data isn't "protected" even with `const`

The `const` type qualifier manages access to the member functions of a type as well as the access to its members.  Since your member `B & b` is a reference, `const` doesn't do much for you here: A reference cannot be changed after initialization either way.  How you access the *target* of that reference isn't even considered:

```
const A a(b);
a.b.non_const_function(); // OOPS, no problem!
```

### solution with templates

Instead of (ab)using the `const` type qualifier you could add a "flag" to your type, to differentiate between cases where you need to be able to have non-const access and case where you don't:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct B {
    void danger() {
    }
    void all_fine() const {
    }
};

template<bool Writeable>
struct A {
    using BRef = typename std::conditional<Writeable, B &, B const &>::type;
    BRef b;

    A (BRef b) : b(b) {};
};

using ConstA = A<false>;
using NonConstA = A<true>;

int main() {
    B b;
    ConstA a(b);
    //NonConstA nc_a(a);
    ConstA another_a(a);
    //another_a.b.danger();
    another_a.b.all_fine();

    NonConstA a2(b);
    a2.b.danger();
}
```

With some `std::enable_if` you can then selectively enable / disable member functions of `A` depending on whether they need "writeable" `b` or not.

### real solution: refactor your design

**BUT** I'd like to highlight this comment even more:

> *"Sometimes b must be read-only, sometimes it is writeable."* All your problems stem from this weird duality. I suggest picking one set of semantics for your class, not two
>
> From [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit)

You should probably instead consider splitting your class such that you have a `CommonA` with functionality used by both a `WriteableA` and a `NonWriteableA` (the names are terrible, but I hope you understand what I mean).

Comment: You are right, I didn't give the full story. I have this "design" where you return the b as const or non-const, like this: `B& Get_b() { return b };` `const B& Get_b() const { return b; }`, which I am not very fond of anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it for the heap:

```
static const A *constCopy(const A &a); // and of course implement it somewhere
```

Then you will not accidentally modify the object via the pointer you get (which has to be stored in `const A *`, otherwise the compiler will complain).

However it will not work with stack-based objects, as returning `const A &` of a local variable is a rather deadly action, and "const constructor" has not been invented yet (related: [Why does C++ not have a const constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936124/why-does-c-not-have-a-const-constructor))